# Terminal management tool for VMs -TUI

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, terminal, memory-management

I want a tool (terminal based) that will list all the VMs, mark the running once, write how much time the VM is up, when was the last connection to it (via ssh).
And also give me an easy option to halt/remove it.

I'm working on a Linux server, that runs many VMs, that several of them are mine.
Other users also have vms on the same server.
Every once in a while, the server RAM is finished, due to the usage of the VMs. (the server has 250GB RAM).

I need a tool to see all the exists VMs on the server, all the running VMs, and to have an option to halt/remove them.

Notice: I'm aware of the tool "vboxmanage". It's not good enough.

Any ideas?

Comment: after searching the net a little more, I found this tool, which is not mature enogh, but it's exactly the kind of thing I looked for:

https://github.com/philsc/vbox-tui